# "Simple" ordered fields proof: show that $0<y^{-1}<1$

Tags: ordered-fields

Given that $x>0$ and $y=x+1$ show that $0<y^{-1}<1$ specifying what proprieties of the Ordered Field you are using.

I really struggle to understand whether I have demonstrated the theorem properly or not.

Comment: Hello Pietro and welcome to MSE! What were your efforts to solve this problem?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch First I used the transitive property of the order to show that y>0, so that it could be inverted

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch than I don't really know how to rigorously show that y>0+1 and than to conclude the demonstration

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch sorry if I'm not correct grammar-wise but English isn't my first language:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Use the following facts:

- (Adding inequalities) $a\le b$ and $c\le d$ implies $a+c\le b+d$,
- If $0<a<b$, then $0<\frac1b<\frac1a$.

Comment: Thank you. The concept was pretty clear in my head, but those really helped me writing it down proprely

Comment: @PietroPasquini You are welcome!